# Pandas DataFrame:Remove rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with columns `roll` , `name` and `present`. I'm trying to remove data where `name == marcus` and `present == False`.

```
        roll    name    present
    0    123     bruno     False
    1    123     bruno     False
    2    123     bruno     True
    3    78      marcus    False       (Remove this row)
    4    78      marcus    True
    5    78      marcus    True
```

Output:

```
        roll    name    present
    0    123     bruno     False
    1    123     bruno     False
    2    123     bruno     True
    4    78      marcus    True
    5    78      marcus    True
```

Is it possible to remove that row without splitting tht dataframe

Comment: `df = df[~((df['name'] == 'marcus') & (df['present'] == False))]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df = df[~((df.name == 'marcus') & (df.present == False))]
```

Comment: This will only keep the row that the OP wants to remove!

Answer (score 0):

Just do a selection:

```py
df = df[(df['name'] != 'marcus') & (df['present'] != False)]
```

Remember to check for where name NOT equals marcus and present NOT equals False, because that is what you want to keep!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
df = df[!((df['name'] == 'marcus') && (df['present'] == False))]
```